# How do I bind the Kendo Textbox control to its data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have designed a view using some of the Kendo Telerik controls. I am not sure how to bind their controls to data.

This generated scaffolded method works :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.surName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

How do I bind the Kendo Textbox?

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
    .Name("fName") 
    .HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "First Name", required = "required", validationmessage="Enter First Name" })
)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `Kendo().TextBoxFor` method:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
    .Name("fName")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "First Name", required = "required", validationmessage="Enter First Name" })
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I get an error when adding the .Value(Model.surName) Object reference not set to an instance of an object? The TextBoxFor was accepted but does not bind without the .value?

Comment: Looks like your model is `null`? `surName` can be empty I think. I don't think you need to use `.Value(Model.surName)`. Note that I used `TextBoxFor`

Comment: Was looking around and saw this. Looks like your field names are mixed. The field **surName** is not the same field as **fName**. The fact Kendo is used should not affect what happens, only how it is rendered.